# How can I see what people are searching for on the Android Market? (i.e. Google Insights for Android Market?)

Tags: google-play-store, search

I'm interested in launching my application to the Android market, however I'm not sure if there is a market for my idea. Is there anyway to see what people are searching for on the android market, and to see how popular various searches are? I'd like to be able to put in a query and see how many searches there are for that query. Google do this for the normal web searches, [Google Insights for Search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/). Is there anything like that for the android market?

Example: I'd like to know which is a more popular search on the android market: "Motorbike" or "Motorcycle". You can do this for Google search engine using Google Insights

Answer (score 3):

[AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com) will show you who is searching for what. They even show broken down by country, age group and many other areas. You can see what is "Hot Today" or even this week or year. If you load the app on your phone it can make recommendations on what you may like based on what you currently have installed.

Comment: I asked them (http://twitter.com/#!/TheAppBrain/status/4930324500848640), they said they don't do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about feeds from the google market, but [Cyrket](http://www.cyrket.com/m/android/) aggregates this sort of data.